# Set Theory and Logic

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Given, $A$ and $B$ are disjoint, prove that $A - B = A$.

I don't have any problem with the question itself. The proof was fairly simple and straight forward until I noticed something.

Let $y \in A$.
$$\implies y \in A \textrm{ and }  y \not\in B$$
$$\implies y \in A - B$$
$$\implies A \subseteq A - B$$

This last step is where I have problem. Why shouldn't it directly imply that $A=A-B$?

My teacher told that "we have proved that every element of $A$ belongs to $A-B$ but not yet proved that those are the only elements in $A-B$"

But how can $A-B$ ever have more elements than $A$?

Is there a flaw in my logic?

Comment: You also have to prove that $A - B \subseteq A$ to establish equality. This is the standard way to prove two sets are equal so it is worth understanding.

Comment: Hopefully you can see how "but how could it be false?" isn't even a response to "we haven't proven this to be true".  If you want to respond to that you would need to point out specifically where you think it's already been proven.

Comment: @BrianMoehring, so can I say that "since $A-B$ cannot have more elements than A, therefore proved...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your intuition is correct but this needs to be verified mathematically through proof. To show that $A-B=A$ you can show that $A\subseteq A-B$ and then that $A-B \subseteq A$. The proof for this is essentially identical to what you have shown already.